# Passing arrays to different ADA package

Tags: arrays, package, ada

I have an assignment in Ada which requires that I pass multiple arrays to a procedure inside a separate package from my main code. I have searched around, but the “solutions” don’t seem to address my situation and have left me even more confused.

I have seen examples where you have to define the array as a type (`TYPE IntArray IS ARRAY (Integer RANGE <>) OF Integer`), but that seems to only work when passing from one procedure to another within the same package - how can I share the array *between* packages?

```
    --multistack.ads
        GENERIC
...
           TYPE Item IS PRIVATE;
           WITH PROCEDURE Put(Job: IN Item);
           PACKAGE MultiStack IS
...
              TYPE IntArray IS ARRAY (Integer RANGE <>) OF Integer;      
              TYPE StackArray IS ARRAY (Integer RANGE <>) OF Item;

              Base:IntArray(1..NumberOfStacks);
...
           END MultiStack;
```

and

```
--stackmove.ads
    WITH MultiStack;
        GENERIC
          TYPE Item IS PRIVATE;
          PACKAGE StackMove IS
             PROCEDURE ReallocateArray(Base:IN OUT MultiStack.IntArray);
     END StackMove;
```

I end up with error `stackmove.ads:13:160: invalid prefix in selected component "MultiStack"`

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  If you're getting an error, please post some code and let us know what error you're getting.

Comment: I dont know what kind of college class you are taking but if your curriculum requires you to work in Ada in the future, I strongly suggest you read the book by Barnes.

Comment: The error message you show in the last paragraph of the question refers to line 13 column 160, but the code you show has only 7 lines and meny fewer than 160 columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a type `Int_Array` in the specification (visible part) of package `Package_1`, and you want to refer to that type in package `Package_2`, you need to use `with` clauses to make the type name visible:

```
with Package_1;
package Package_2 is

    procedure Something (A : Package_1.Int_Array);

    -- .........

end Package_2;
```

or

```
with Package_1;  use Package_1;
package Package_2 is

    procedure Something (A : Int_Array);

    -- .........

end Package_2;
```

`with Package_1` is needed to make anything defined in `Package_1` available.  Even then, you have to use a qualifier `Package_1.` in front of any identifier defined there, to let the compiler know that's where to find it.  `use Package_1` means you can use the names defined in `Package_1` without that qualifier.  However, using `use` can make it more difficult for a reader to tell where the names are coming from, especially if you `use` too many packages.  Different Ada programmers have different opinions about whether to use `use` and when.

If this is not the issue, please post more information.

**MORE:** OK, since your packages are `generic`, you have a rather different problem.

The generic package `MultiStack` doesn't actually define a type `IntArray` that you can use.  The only way you can use it is to instantiate the generic.  If you define `Inst` to be an instance of the generic, like this:

```
package Inst is new MultiStack (Item => Some_Type, Put => Some_Put_Procedure);
```

then you can refer to `Inst.IntArray`.  But `MultiStack.IntArray` is never going to be legal outside of `MultiStack` itself.

So to get this to work with `StackMove`, there are two possibilities, and you'll need to decide depending on what your needs are: (1) There will be a specific instance `My_Multistack` that you've already instantiated, that `StackMove` will work with; (2) more likely, you'd like `StackMove` to work with any instance of `MultiStack`.  If (1) is correct, then just change `MultiStack` to `My_MultiStack` in `stackmove.ads`.  But if you want (2), you'll need a *generic formal package*:

```
with MultiStack;
generic
    type Item is private;
    with package Stack_Instance is new MultiStack(<>);
package StackMove is
    procedure ReallocateArray (Base : in out Stack_Instance.IntArray);
end StackMove;
```

(You can put `Item` and `Stack_Instance` in either order.)

Doing the above won't guarantee that the `Stack_Instance` was instantiated with the same `Item` as `StackMove`.  If you want to guarantee that:

```
with MultiStack;
generic
    type Item is private;
    with package Stack_Instance is new MultiStack(Item => Item, Put => <>);
package StackMove is
    procedure ReallocateArray (Base : in out Stack_Instance.IntArray);
end StackMove;
```

Then `StackMove` will work only with a `MultiStack` that was instantiated with the same `Item`; the good news is that now the compiler can be certain that the two `Item` types are the same, so you won't get type conflicts.

To instantiate, using the same `Inst` example as above:

```
package Inst is new MultiStack (Item => Some_Type, Put => Some_Put_Procedure);
package StackMove_Inst is new StackMove (Item => Some_Type, Stack_Instance => Inst);
```

[The above two don't have to be together like that; they can be in different packages.]

Comment: I tried something similar to this but still get `invalid prefix in selected component "MultiStack"`.  I have updated my question.

Comment: @DaWood You didn't say it was generic--that changes a lot of things.